# How to add a class to the Django countries widget

Tags: python, django, countries, django-countries

Hi I am trying to use a Django plugin called django-countries to add a select with all the countries, sofar It's working but how can I add a html class to the select?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Django, a form field is rendered into an HTML representation using a [widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/).

Typically, you can make the widget render class and other HTML attributes by specifying these as arguments to the widget when you are defining your form. For example:

```
from django import forms

class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    comment = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"class": "my-class"})
    )
```

Given your question relates to a custom field in [django-countries](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries) you should try the same by passing your custom attributes when instantiating a [CountrySelectWidget](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries#countryselectwidget) instance. For example:

```
from django import forms
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from django_countries.widgets import CountrySelectWidget

class CustomForm(forms.Form):
    country = CountryField().formfield(
        widget=CountrySelectWidget(
           attrs={"class": "my-class"}
        )
    )
```